# iOS: UIWebView with HTML+gif

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, animated-gif

I used a UIWebview to load a HTML file inside my source package. The HTML with an animated gif inside. However, I found that sometimes, when I load the view, the gif stopped animated. What I did is then go to another page and back, the gif move again. I have tried to reload the webView every time in viewDidLoad() and viewWillAppear() with the following code:

```
let imageName = "myPage"
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: imageName, withExtension: "html")
if (url == nil) {
  debugPrint("webview nil", imageName)
  return
}
let request = NSURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60.0)

URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
}
```

What is the problem that caused the animated gif stopped sometime? 
My UIView is simple, just with a single UIWebView occupied the whole page.

The HTML page is also simple -- just with an image source of animated gif image.

Comment: `UIWebView` is deprecated for a long time. Use `WKWebView` instead.

Comment: @user6539552 : Rather than trying to load gif in webpage as anyway u r loading html page why don't you write simple CSS animation to replicate the behavior of Gif just a suggestion I know not the solution to ur problem :)

Comment: There is some user requirement that not allow me to do so :'(